# Drupal as a CMS and CodeIgniter as a framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, drupal

Is it possible to create a web application using Drupal as a CMS and CodeIgniter as a framework?

Comment: Drupal basically is a framework as well, just a bigger one. What/how/why would you want to merge these two?

Comment: You could sort of do this, but it's probably not for beginners. If you have separate content and application sections, it would be easy (using mod_rewrite to direct requests to different controllers) but when you want to include a CI partial in Drupal, or a Drupal module in a CI page, it would probably start to get a bit messy. Both will use different database access systems, I should think. If you have a lot of application development, I'd stick to a framework, personally.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal does not really need something like CI and vice versa. If you are building a web application in Drupal and you really feel the need to have something like CI, then you should simply write your entire application in CI.

Drupal is somewhat of a prebuild house for a web application. You install it, already have everything in place like a backend, caching, login-mechanism, etc. Next you add some modules, customize a theme and done. Just like decorating your living room or building an extra garage.

CI is more of a solid foundation to build a house on. It has some functionality but you need to write your own functionality if you want everything you need. You need to build walls and all that stuff but in the end you have had 100% control over just about anything.

I don't see the point of having 2 bases for a web applications. Just makes things more complicated imho. Just pick Drupal if you want a more extended base than just a framework. Or pick CI if you want to build everything up from "just a framework".

Answer (score 0):

First decide whether you want to build a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) or not.

If you want to build a CMS then you can choose Drupal or [Expression Engine](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine) or any other CMS frameworks like Joomla. The advantage of using Expression Engine is it is built on top of Codeigniter and you can add custom modules using Codeigniter/php style of coding.

If you don't want to build a CMS, then since you are familiar with Codeigniter, build a web application using only Codeigniter